# Select data and use where and where laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.6

I am trying to create ( (Where and Where) OR (Where and Where) ) And after a lot of searching I found this

```
  $last_transations = Transcationhistorique::where('sender_id', '=', $user_id)
                            ->where('receiver_id','=', $user_id)
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->skip(3)
                            ->take(3)
                            ->get();
```

I get a empty result

> "last 3 transactions": []

Comment: Is it possible to have the same user Id on `sender_id` and `receiver_id`?

Comment: Why do use put the same `$user_id` for `sender` and `receiver`?

Comment: i want to select all transaction for this user (send or receive)

Comment: Check your query, according to me your query implies, you want all the record where `sender_id` and `receiver_id` is equal to $user_id

Comment: And what was your expectation?

Comment: I want to select the 3 last transaction that this user do it if he send or he is the receiver

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are searching for simple `where or where` then use (using your query):

```
$last_transations = Transcationhistorique::where('sender_id', $user_id)
                    ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(3)->take(3)->get();
```

If you are searching `where and where` then use (using your query):

```
$last_transations = Transcationhistorique::where(['sender_id' => $user_id, 'receiver_id' => $user_id])
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(3)->take(3)->get();
```

If you are searching for `(where and where) OR (where and where)` , thats a bit complicated, you will make your query like:

```
DB::table('users')
   ->where(['col1' => 'val1', 'col2' => 'val2'])
   ->orWhere(function ($query) {
         $query->where(['col3' => 'val3', 'col4' => 'val4']);
   })
   ->get();
```

Refererence [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses)

Comment: also i get a empty result

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi if you are getting empty it means there is no match! Are you sure there are same user id in `sender_id` and `receiver_id` columns?

Comment: write a normal MySQL query which is producing result for you and i will tell you its eloquent equivalent

Comment: I want to select the 3 last transaction that this user do it if he send or he is the receiver

Comment: As i said, write a normal MySQL query which is producing result for you, we dont know what is your table structure and all, the query will help to understand

Comment: @AhmedGuesmi you want the where or where variant of this awnsers. you want all records where the user send something *or* recieved something. if you do where and where the user needs to send it to itself to pop up

Comment: No problem, glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

I think you are specifying skip and take values wrong, can you try the below:

```
$last_transations = Transcationhistorique::where('sender_id', $user_id)
                    ->orWhere('receiver_id', $user_id)
                    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->skip(0)->take(3)->get();
```

From docs it says:

> **skip / take**: To limit the number of results returned from the query, or to skip a
>   given number of results in the query, you may use the skip and take
>   methods:

What you're doing is that skip 3 and take 3 so it will be like `->offset(3)->limit(3)` which will return empty!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [where](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries) and pass a functions to it For example :

if I want to get the user who is admin and have id 4 or 5

```
$users->where("type","admin")->where(function($query){
        $query->where("id",4)->orWhere("id",5);
    })->get();
```

It is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE type = "admin" AND (id = 4 OR id = 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $last_transations = Transcationhistorique::where([['sender_id', '=', $user_id],['receiver_id','=', $user_id]])
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
                            ->skip(3)
                            ->take(3)
                            ->get();
```

There you go.